# jQuery set value according to window width

Tags: jquery, window, width

For starters; Im a big jQuery/Javascript newbie.
Im making a responsive website which is including the SlidesJS slider.
My fundamental problem is that I wonna change the height of the slider according to the window width:

If window width < 767px set height to 600.
else set height to 400.

You set the SlidesJS value with this jQuery code(the height i want to make flexible):

```
$(function() {
$('#slides').slidesjs({
width: 940,
height: 400,
play: {
active: true,
auto: true,
interval: 4000,
swap: true
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$(function() {
    $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: setWindowHeight(),
        play: {
            active: true,
            auto: true,
            interval: 4000,
            swap: true
        }
    });
});

function setWindowHeight() {
    return ($(window).width() < 767) ? 600 : 400;   
}
```